# How to delete all of data by SQLiteDatabase in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

my_table(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name NVARCHAR(100))
I deleted all of the data in SQLiteDatabase by the command "DELETE FROM my_table". It's was a success, but I have one trouble: When I insert new data into my_table, ID auto-increment with the old ID, It means have field memory is existing in my program. Can you help me solve it? Thank everybody
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DW9G.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, there is an internal table called `sqlite_sequence` which stored information about `autoincrement` columns. To reset autoincrement value, you can execute command:

> "DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + my_table + "'"